# How to search in a DB with a string parameter

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem making a proper SQL string and insert a variable containing a string.

I thought I could use:

```php
function get_search_books($parameters)
{
    $result = queryDatabase(
        "SELECT title FROM book WHERE title LIKE '%?%'",
        array(1 => $parameters[0])
    );
    //...
}
```

but this doesent seem to work...

Do anyone have an idea of how this is done with a string variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the character `%` within your parameter, during binding phase.
Try with this:

```
$result = queryDatabase(
    "SELECT title FROM book WHERE title LIKE ?",
    array(1 => '%' . $parameters[0] . '%')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

your should first check the query by inserting raw value, that is in the database. than check whats wrong. in this way you can be sure if the error is in sql or in array that you are passing as parameter

```
"SELECT title FROM book WHERE title LIKE '%anythingindatabase%'",
```

Comment: I'v already tried that, and sure it works, but i want it to be generalized into a function which places the string variable into the query...

Comment: what does the array look like, can you elaborate